# Why is this low quality flag incorrect for this audit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

My recent incorrect review can be found below:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/33183664

I flagged this one as very low quality, because it contains very little information, isn't reproducible, and wasn't even tagged correctly (the example given before review was tagged as an R question). What is the correct response to this question and why? I looked for hints [at this link about the flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer/167641#167641), but the only two parts here that seem to qualify are highlighted below:

[image]

For me, the question is still not completely understandable because the question name just says what happened without providing any context for somebody to reasonably answer. The third part seems to be a generic catch all that could be technically applied to many flags/comments. The "needs details/clarity" flag also seems too broad, as it doesn't apply to how little effort was put into this question.

Comment: The text right above the part in your screenshot says _"You should **not** use it to describe the following, but should be using comments, close votes, downvotes and / or edits instead"_

Comment: Right. But to me these don't really qualify for these actions, which is why I highlighted them and added my reasons for why they dont. Of course I could be wrong, but it seems confusing when the flag is supposed to be used for low quality posts.

Comment: This might not be the best audit but why do you think a VLQ flag is applicable? Again, from the answer you linked to: _"The post is an indecipherable mess"_ and _"Casting close votes and down votes is simply not enough here"_. That's what a VLQ flag is for. Do you think that that applies here?

Comment: Whether this is a good audit or not, [the question did enter Hot Network Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74226250/timeline) and thus popularity might trump clarity and making this a "known-good" audit. Note that there were few others who failed the audit though.

Comment: So the correct path is to just comment or share feedback then? Looking through the post above from 416, the VLQ flag doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: Put another way, VLQ should be used for questions that are **clearly** off-topic ***or*** so poorly written that you can't determine if they are on-topic (not to detract from the additional reasons). Don't use the flag to save yourself -1 for downvoting, if it's an audit you'll fail. See all the text at the second link in your question: "If you use the 'Very Low Quality' flag, you're sending a signal to moderators that the delete button probably needs to be pushed.", so you're not going to want to do that if you should do something else.

Comment: @Rob you can't "save yourself -1 for downvoting" for questions :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, rather than hiding your wisdom in a comment it would be more helpful if you would add it to this post: [Review Flowchart](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300659/282094): "On **SO**, the LQ review queue **only** contains **answers**. ... - Edit: if the post can be fixed by an edit, user will dequeue the question once the edit is applied.".